# С++ Задача на спички

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть задача на C++. Задачу вроде решил правильно, ответы выводит нужные, но когда загружаю решение пишет ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? Тестировал уже сто раз как мог, вроде ошибок нету. Почему не принимает не понимаю. Код прилагаю.

Задача: Паша и Миша играют в игру. Сегодня они играют в нее t раз. Правила игры такие. На столе лежит q спичек и есть максимальное число спичек которое 1 игрок может взять за один ход это z. (z не может быть больше q). Каждый ход игроки по очереди берут от 1 до z спичек. Паша всегда начинает первый. Надо вывести сколько в каждой игре Паше надо взять спичек на первом ходу, для того чтобы гарантировано выиграть, а если это невозможно вывести 0.

## Ввод:

3

5 3

9 4

3 2

## Вывод:

1 4 0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t, q, z, e;
long long int x[10000], n[10000];
cin>>t;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
cin>>x[i]>>n[i];
    q=x[i];
    z=n[i];
    if(q < 1 && z < 1){cout<<"0"<<endl;return 0;}
    if(q==z){cout<<"1"<<endl;return 0;}else{
    for(int i=1;i<q;i++)
    {
        if((q-i)==z+1 && i<=z)
        {cout<<i<<endl;break;}
        if(i==q-1){cout<<"0"<<endl;break;}
    }}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да по сути нужно просто выводить `q%(z+1)`. Сами разберетесь, почему? Ну и сами напишете?

Кстати, вот проверьте пару примеров - ваша программа дает для 141 и 10 ответ 0, хотя на самом деле верный ответ - 9, или там 68 и 4 - ваша дает 0, правильный ответ - 3...

Comment: Спасибо, понял!